# Read multiline JSON using apache beam / google cloud dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to read a JSON file (multi-line) in the pipeline but `beam.io.ReadFromText(somefile.json` reads one line at a time.

I am trying to read the content of the file as JSON so that I can apply `map` on each category to download relevant products file.

This is how my `JSON` file **(productindex.json)** looks like:

```
{
  "productcategories" : {
    "category1" : {
      "productfile" : "http://products.somestore.com/category1/products.json"
    },
    "category2" : {
      "productfile" : "http://products.somestore.com/category2/products.json"
    },
    "category3" : {
      "productfile" : "http://products.somestore.com/category3/products.json"
    },
    "category4" : {
      "productfile" : "http://products.somestore.com/category4/products.json"
    }
}
```

This is how the beginning of my pipeline looks like:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    rows = (
        p | beam.io.ReadFromText(
            "http://products.somestore.com/allproducts/productindex.json")
    )
```

I am using `apache-beam[gcp]` module.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I'm currently using the Java SDK of Apache Beam, but had the same issue. I solved my issue with `jsonString.replaceAll("\\R", " ")`. That regex will detect newline and return characters. This replacement will flatten your json into a single line. In Python it would be something like `jsonString.replace("\n\r", " ")`.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Beam / Cloud Dataflow does not directly support reading multi-line Json data.

The primary reason is that this is very hard to do in parallel. How does Beam know where each record ends? This is easy for a single reader, but very complicated for parallel readers.

The best solution that I can recommend is to convert your Json data into Newline-delimited Json (NDJSON) before processing by Beam / Dataflow. This may be as simple as changing the output format written by the upstream task or may require pre-processing.

Comment: Apache Beam newb here. Would dearly love to know how to do this conversion. I am looking at some really nested JSON files.

Comment: @rocksNwaves - Reading JSON is supported by just about all languages natively or via libraries. Post a new question on how to process JSON.